# how to solve type script error is not assignable to parameter of type?

Tags: typescript

any idea how to explain to type script that am passing the same required argument ? I am getting the following error (is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: ""; } ) if you could please insert how would you declare types in case you would use this solution.

```js
  const initialState = { name: '', gender: '', height: '', weight: '' };
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<{ [key: string]: '' }>(initialState);
```

I tried this solution but seem like duplicate code

```js
  type state = { [key: string]: '' };
  const initialState: state = { name: '', gender: '', measurements: '', height: '', weight: '' };
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<state>(initialState);
```

Comment: Because your type `{ [key: string]: '' }` states that the object can only contain properties whose values are the empty string. If that's what you want, use a `const` type assertion when you initialize it: `const initialState = { name: '', gender: '', height: '', weight: '' } as const;` which will capture the literal types of the initial property values. However, if as I suspect, you want subsequent States to be able to have other strings as property values, instead use type inference instead of passing an explicit type argument: `const [selected, setSelected] = useState(initialState);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a better way to say the same thing:

```js
const initialState = { name: '', gender: '', height: '', weight: '' };
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<typeof initialState>(initialState);
```

The problem with your approach is the way TypeScript is inferring the type and the way you are thinking it should.

You are thinking the inferred type looks like this:

```
{ [key: string]: '' }
```

Which means key can be any arbitrary string but the values can only be empty string i.e. `''`.

While the way typescript is inferring it, (and more commonly this is what one wants) is as follows

```js
{
    name: string;
    gender: string;
    height: string;
    weight: string;
}
```

So, when you say,

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<{ [key: string]: '' }>(initialState);
```

You are assigning a wider type to a narrower type. TypeScript is thinking the `initialState` can have `string` type as values while you are implying that it cannot have anything other than empty string. Hence the error.

The another problem with your `{ [key: string]: '' }` typing is you are allowing keys to be any string. Which is fine if you want any arbitrary object as state. (you could have used `Record<string, string>`). But in majority of cases, you'd want stricter typing. So, you should use this instead:

```js
<typeof initialState>
```

But hey, since TypeScript is doing the hard work for you, this should be just fine:

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(initialState);
```

Comment: I dont want to use inference so i make it like this   type state = { [key: string]: string };

Comment: as I understand initialState = { name: ''} if ts does it inference will think I need only empty strings as value ? , rather than empty string that will change to different values ?

Comment: Most of the times when you say, `const t = {foo: 1, bar: ''}` you intend type of `t` should be `{foo: number, bar: string}`. And, that's what TS does. It would be a lot of boilerplate code if TS infers the type as `{foo: 1, bar: ''}` because in that case, you won't be able to do things like `t.bar = 'baz'` because type definition allows only `''` to be the value of `bar`. But if that's what you want you can do [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) by saying `const t = {foo: 1, bar: ''} as const`.